# Sci fi movie with gryphon that chases people through the seven wonders of the ancient world

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie back in the 80s, I think. It was about a scientist who raises a gryphon that chases his son and other scientists through the seven wonders of the ancient world and ends with them at the hall of knowledge.

Comment: Where (what country) and in what medium (theater, rental film, VHS, pay TV, broadcast TV)?  What language?

Answer (score 2):

Partial match, with a different "monster" and from 2008, *[Riddles of the Sphinx](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0976167/)*. From an entry about the [Cipher Key](http://moa.omnimulti.com/Cipher_Key_(Riddle_of_the_Sphinx)), the artifact of the film:

> In the 21st century, the head of Sentinel Thomas Parr uncovered the two pieces of the Cipher Stone. He spent days translating the writings of the artifact with teams of researchers aiding him in the process. However, he was unaware that his work had been sabotaged and the primer that he used for translation was wrong which mistakenly led him to believe the Cipher Key was the means to gain entry into the **Hall of Knowledge**. Taking a small team with him along with his aide Jessica, he placed the Key into its slot but this act simply awakened the **demonic sphinx** that butchered all before it. Thomas Parr gave the Cipher Key to Jessica and told her to get the aid of **his son Robert Parr** after which Thomas sacrificed his life by distracting the Sphinx thus allowing Jessica to escape. Unknown to her, the demonic Sphinx was charged with a divine duty of hunting down the bearer of the Cipher Key and killing them for their wrongful actions. She later managed to get the reluctant aide of Robert when the Sphinx attacked forcing him and his daughter Karen Parr to flee to the safety of Sentinel.
>
> Once there, they began getting the aid of Field Agent Ryder who gave them the resources they needed to solve the riddles of the Cipher Key as legend said that within three days of its wrong usage; the sphinx would bring forth the Plague of Isis that would wipe out mankind in order to safeguard the treasures of the Hall of Knowledge. This led them to first journey to Greece where they uncovered the first stone, than to Iraq after Ryder gained military cooperation by a direct line to the United States President where they acquired the second stone. The third stone they mistakenly searched for in Alexandria before they learnt that it was actually within the Egyptian Sphinx which they uncovered. The fourth stone was also discovered within the Egyptian Sphinx that represented the element of earth and with the crystals brought together they formed the Ankh of Destiny. Whilst observing it, a new riddle was present on it which Sentinel field agent Ryder deciphered by himself. This led to the revelation that it was he who was responsible for sabotaging Thomas Parr's primer translation because Ryder wanted access to the Hall of Knowledge. This was based on his frustrations of Thomas preventing him from acquiring many discoveries and thus he desired to learn the secrets of existence. After taking the Ankh of Destiny, Ryder was attacked by the Sphinx and tried to kill it but failed as he did not realize how to use the mystical artifact. Later, Robert Parr took the Ankh and learnt the true meaning of the riddle and stabbed himself with the Ankh of Destiny which killed the Sphinx. Robert was later taken to the Hall of Knowledge as a result and the Plague of Isis was stopped from wiping out mankind.

....

> Following the creation of the interdimensional chamber of the Hall of Knowledge, other such dimensional pockets were established in Ancient Greece, Babylon and Egypt located by the **Seven Wonders of the world**.

### Trailer

The depiction of the Sphinx, being a leonine creature with bird wings, does resemble a gryphon.

[image: The Sphinx, readying to attack]

Comment: I'm not the OP, but when I saw the description of the film in the question, I immediately thought of this. It fits pretty much perfectly, with the caveats you gave. However, I would like to offer a warning to anyone reading this Q&A: I can tell you, from bitter personal experience, that this is not a film worth watching _for any reason_. It's _terrible_. Just say no, kids - it's the only way.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to answer, I had a medical emergency and landed in the hospital and then a nursing home. Better now. This is the movie I have been looking for forever.  THANK YOU!

Comment: @user149990 You can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. :) Congrats! And I hope your life is going better.